# Pig parameter substitution based on the environment

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way to define all properties, which vary by environment (dev, qa, prod), in a namespaced configuration file (which has sections for each environment) and ask pig to read the appropriate properties based on an environment variable which identifies whether it is dev, qa, or prod.

If the above is not possible, can we use a unix environment variable in a pig script which specifies the location to read/write data (apart from using parameters).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why apart from using parameters? When you call your Pig script, you can send the value of the environment variable as a parameter (via Pig's command-line options).

Comment: no reason really...just wanted to know what other options we have

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/advanced_pig_latin.html) for "Parameter Substitution".  It describes how to set up a parameter file.